# Using currentTimeMillis and it's 6 hours off

Tags: java, calendar

I have a function that will output yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss. Everything is perfectly accurate except the hour, which appears to be 6 hours ahead. Any ideas as to why?

```
public static void dateAndTime() {
   Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1;
    int day = cal.get(Calendar.DATE);
    int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);

    long totalMilliseconds = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long totalSeconds = totalMilliseconds / 1000;
    int currentSecond = (int)(totalSeconds % 60);
    long totalMinutes = totalSeconds / 60;
    int currentMinute = (int)(totalMinutes % 60);
    long totalHours = totalMinutes / 60;
    int currentHour = (int)(totalHours % 24);
       System.out.println (year + "-" + month + "-" + day + " " + currentHour + ":" + currentMinute + ":" + currentSecond);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[`currentTimeMillis()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis%28%29) gives you the number of milliseconds that has elapsed since a fixed point in time called [the Unix epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time):  **00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 1970**.

Here's one way of getting the correct time:

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.TimeZone;
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

class Clock {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Athens"));
        Date currentDate = new Date();
        System.out.println(df.format(currentDate));
    }
}
```

Output (local time in Athens):

```
2013-08-24 23:54:45
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a time-zone related issue. The `Calendar` class defaults to your local time zone whereas the method System.currentTimeMillis() returns (as specified in the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis%28%29)):

> the difference, measured in milliseconds, between the current time and midnight, January 1, 1970 UTC.